# How to convert dictionary data in to dataframe from JSON file in R?

Tags: r, json, dictionary, dataframe, rjson

I'm new to the R. And I want to read the JSON file and convert into tabular structure file. Can you please help me how to convert the following data into the tabular structure format. The data is in JSON file as follows:

```
{"Physics":8,"Chemistry":7,"PhysicalEducation":6,"English":7,"Mathematics":7,"serial":47738}
{"Physics":1,"Chemistry":1,"PhysicalEducation":1,"English":3,"Mathematics":2,"serial":85520}
{"Physics":2,"Chemistry":1,"Biology":2,"English":4,"Mathematics":8,"serial":182318}
{"Physics":3,"Chemistry":4,"PhysicalEducation":5,"English":5,"Mathematics":8,"serial":77482}
{"Accountancy":2,"BusinessStudies":5,"Economics":3,"English":6,"Mathematics":7,"serial":152940}
```

And I want to convert into like this

```
Sub1 Sub2 Sub3 Sub4 Sub5 Serial
 8    7    6    7   7    47738
 1    1    1    3   2    85520  
 2    1    2    4   8    182318
 3    4    5    5   8    77482
 2    5    3    6   7    152940
```

Can you please help me how to do that in R. Your help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(rjson)
Lines <- readLines("training_backup.json") 
json_df <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(Lines, fromJSON)))
rownames(json_df) <- NULL
```

Updated Answer