# Key-value pairs with character data to a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, rjson

I had been [following this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53424732/how-to-convert-dictionary-data-in-to-dataframe-from-json-file-in-r) for how to convert a key-value dictionary to a dataframe in R using `rjson`, but I can't seem to get it to work with my data:

```
{"tagid":493,"name":"Early Access","count":75}
{"tagid":599,"name":"Simulation","count":68,"browseable":true}
{"tagid":1755,"name":"Space","count":64,"browseable":true}
```

Doesn't seem to want to parse into a dataframe because of the character values for the `name` key:

`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unexpected character '''`

I'm using the same code as the example I linked to:

```
library(rjson)
Lines <- readLines("clipboard") 
json_df <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(Lines, fromJSON)))
```

Is there a way to do a similar conversion of the dictionary data to a data frame here if there's character data?

Edit: the following script is what I'm using to generate the data:

```
webpage <- read_html("https://store.steampowered.com/app/387290")
data <- html_nodes(webpage, css = "script") %>% html_text()

tag_data <- data[lapply(data,function(x) length(grep("InitAppTagModal",x,value=FALSE))) == 1]
tag_data <- regmatches(tag_data, gregexpr("[?<=\\[].*?[?=\\]]", tag_data, perl=T))[[1]][1]
tag_data <- gsub('[', "", tag_data, fixed = TRUE)
tag_data <- gsub(']', "", tag_data, fixed = TRUE)
tag_data <- gsub("},{", "}\n{", tag_data, fixed = TRUE)

writeLines(tag_data, con = "temp.json", sep = "\n")
tag_df <- stream_in(file("temp.json"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put your example data into a json file. And I named it `test.json`

```
library(jsonlite)

myoutput <- stream_in(file("test.json"))
myoutput

  tagid         name count browseable
1   493 Early Access    75         NA
2   599   Simulation    68       TRUE
3  1755        Space    64       TRUE
```

Comment: This technically works, but I wonder if there's a more straightforward solution that doesn't involve writing a temp file then reading from it.

Comment: @AI52487963 - there will be a "simpler" solution, but we don't know where your JSON is stored or how it was created. Is it in your R session already?

Comment: @SymbolixAU, quite right. I've added an edit showing how I'm generating the data.

Comment: You can call `jsonlite::fromJSON( tag_data )` directly after the `regmatches` line, before all the `gsub()` calls.